# Do we know what stories Boios collected in Ornithogonia?

Tags: greek

The story of [Polyphonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphonte) and her cannibal sons survives in only one source, the *Metamorphoses* of Antoninus Liberalis. Antoninus cites Boios' lost collection of metamorphosis myths *Ornithogonia* as the source of the story.

Do we know of other myths that were in the Ornithogonia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antoninus Liberalis, in his [*Metamorphoses*](https://oniehlibraryofgreekliterature.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/237542527-metamorphoses-of-antoninus-liberalis.pdf), quote ten stories from Boios' *Ornithogonia*: that of Hierax, Aegypius, Anthus, Aedon, Meropis, Oenoe, Eeropus, Clinis, the story about the thieves (*Phores*) in the Idean cave, and, as you mentioned earlier, that of Polyphonte.

In addition, Aemilius Macer's *Ornithogonia* (only known from fragments) are said to be heavily based on Boios' *Ornithogonia* as well. Here is the relevant quote from Adrian Hollis' [Fragments of Roman Poetry C.60 BC-AD 20](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SwqcSJzx7MAC):

> Of the two major works by Aemilius Macer, we know much less about the *Ornithogonia*, though Ovid might have found it more useful (as a source for his *Metamorphoses*). It had at least two books - perhaps just two, like the *Theriaca*. Macer's model would have been a Greek hexameter poem of the same name (also, it seems, in two books) ascribed to one Boeus or Boeo (if the latter, perhaps the legendary Pythian priestess). This may have been composed at the beginning of the Hellenistic age, since it was known to Philochorus (*F. Gr. Hist.* 328 F 214, from Athenaeus 9.393e). No verbatim fragments of the Greek *Ornithogonia* survive - most of those adumbrated in Powell, *Coll. Alex.*, 24-5, would be disowned by any half-decent Greek poet - but the mythographer Antoninus Liberalis (second or third century AD?) in his *Metamorphoses* (the 1968 Budé edition by M. Papathomopoulos is very useful) provides prose paraphrases of ten transformations into birds which are credited, by notes accompanying the text, to the *Ornithogonia* of Boeus.

Transformations mentioned in Macer's *Ornithogonia* include that of Picumnus and Cygnus.